# Gaming question - Is this question acceptable on SuperUser?

Tags: support, migration

I posted the following question on the Gaming site:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48467/stuttering-audio-and-graphics-in-pc-games

Topic was closed and I guess deemed off topic, even though my issue happens while gaming.  I received a comment suggesting getting it migrated to the Superuser sie.

If I moved the topic to Superuser, would I risk having the topic get closed or is it ok for me to ask?  Is there anything about the topic I should improve upon so that I don't end up having it closed *again*?

Comment: Preferably not, if only because there are so many possible causes that its like finding a needle in a haystack

Answer (score 2):

Based on the questions we get and those that stay open, I'd say your question is on-topic. It even contains enough detail to work with, and it's well written.

That being said, these kinds of troubleshooting questions are (obviously) very localized to your situation and your machine. It's likely you'll need to check a few things based on comments you get, etc. And, as [Ivo said](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4181/gaming-question-is-this-question-acceptable-on-superuser#comment10498_4181), it might run into a dead end.

I personally would say, **yes, have it migrated here**, but feel free to come to [Super User Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) if you want to have further discussions. I guess we have a couple of gamers here who can help you!